# Getting "Include of non-modular header inside framework module" after update cocoalumberjack to 3.6.0

Tags: cocoalumberjack

I have installed CocoaLumberjack via cocoapods, because the XMPPFramework add dependency. After updated CocoaLumerjack to the newest version 3.6.0, I got a fatal message:Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'CocoaLumberjack.DDAbstractDatabaseLogger': 'xxx/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h'

Try going Build Settings under "Target" and set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to YES, it's not work for me.
Checked the Apple Developer Forums, Apple Staff replied as below: "Unfortunately, CocoaPods can commonly create header search paths that let the compiler find headers at a location which does not appear (to the compiler) to be a part of a module.
NOTE: The "Allow Non-modular includes in Framework Modules" build setting does not apply to Swift (and it would not be safe if it did, Swift requires access to modules for proper debugging support)."
They described the reason, but I still have no idea to deal with this problem.

error messages:

```
/xxx/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/include/DDAbstractDatabaseLogger.h:21:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'CocoaLumberjack.DDAbstractDatabaseLogger': '/xxx/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h'
/xxx/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/include/DDASLLogCapture.h:16:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'CocoaLumberjack.DDASLLogCapture': '/xxx/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDASLLogger.h'
/xxx/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/include/DDContextFilterLogFormatter.h:23:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'CocoaLumberjack.DDContextFilterLogFormatter': '/xxx/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h'
/xxx/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/include/DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter.h:23:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'CocoaLumberjack.DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter': '/xxx/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h'
/xxx/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/include/DDFileLogger+Buffering.h:16:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'CocoaLumberjack.DDFileLogger_Buffering': '/xxx/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDFileLogger.h'
/xxx/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/include/DDLog+LOGV.h:21:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'CocoaLumberjack.DDLog_LOGV': '/xxx/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h'
/xxx/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/Supporting Files/CocoaLumberjack.h:103:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'CocoaLumberjack.CocoaLumberjack': '/xxx/Pods/Headers/Public/CocoaLumberjack/DDLegacyMacros.h'
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: When I use `pod 'CocoaLumberjack'` in my podfile everything compiles fine. But when I use `pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'` I get these errors when trying to compile the project.

Comment: Also can you link me the thread in the Apple Developer Forums where you asked the same question? Thanks!

Comment: Was it this one? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/23554

Comment: Update: I tried lots of things but couldn't fix the errors. I ended up importing the framework using Carthage instead of CocoaPods. That worked fine.